# Netflix freezes on Firefox w/ Snap on 22.04.1

Tags: firefox, snap, netflix

I have a "TV PC" that is used to watch streaming services. So Netflix, prime, etc...

```
tvpc@tvpc:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
```

Here is my config

```
tvpc@tvpc:~$ inxi
CPU: quad core Intel Xeon X5450 (-MCP-) speed/min/max: 2097/2003/3003 MHz
Kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic x86_64 Up: 39d 16h 20m
Mem: 1755.9/3923.1 MiB (44.8%) Storage: 931.52 GiB (8.9% used) Procs: 237
Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13
```

When I try to run netflix in the snap firefox, the stream plays OK for a few seconds, then freezes for 10 seconds, audio plays, but the video does not. Then it returns to normal for maybe a minute and repeats.

Any idea what could be causing this? Chromium/brave/firefox not snap/Google Chrome all work.

Comment: 2 things to do is to check log files for notices and to start it from command line and see if it shows a creash in the terminal.

Comment: Turns out, the problem is more common than I thought. https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/ynxbci/help_error_mp4parse_found_2_nul_bytes_in_00_error/

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1772085